# Looking for a concise copy constructor implementation (java)

Tags: java, copy-constructor

For 2 variables, the statements are okay to write in the copy constructor block. But for a situation, in which there are several variables, can please someone help me knowing how similar result can be attained? I trier using `this` but it turned out to be a final variable.

```
class Obj
{
    int a, b;

    Obj(int a, int b)
    {this.a = a; this.b =b;}

    Obj(Obj obj1)
    //trying to copy every variable by concise logic here
    //instead of writing for each and every variable
    {a = obj1.a; b = obj1.b;} 
}

class CopyObj2 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Obj obj1 = new Obj(5,10);
        System.out.println("Obj1\t"+obj1.a+", "+obj1.b);
        Obj obj2 = new Obj(obj1);
        System.out.println("Obj2\t"+obj2.a+", "+obj2.b);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what does not work with the code you've shown?

Comment: You can use Lombok. Take a look at this comment: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/908#issuecomment-157161768

Comment: In java, unlike in c++, there is no default copy constructor- you'll have to copy all fields. If you are using eclipse, you can auto-generate a constructor from the member variables (that still isn't what you need though)

Comment: Possibly you could use the Reflection framework.  But unless you were dealing with, say, fifty or more member fields,  I doubt it would be more "concise" (at least in terms of number of lines of code) than just writing out the individual assignments.

Comment: @Lino I didn't say this piece doesn't work, I was looking for an alternative to reduce multiple copying statements

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way to do that - the only way is to assign field values by hand, as you did.

As a helper - you can try to use [Orika](https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika) - Java bean mapping framework (works if your classes are beans).

> I tried using this but it turned out to be a final variable.

`this` is the reference to your object. You can't assign another value to him - it just doesn't make a sense.

Answer (score 0):

The *copy constructor* is used in java's AWT stemming Point, Rectangle, Polygon and other geometric classes. Typically where there are many objects.

One does not need a copy constructor for *immutable* classes with `final` fields.

Experience with mutable classes let me tend to advise switching to immutable classes.
With copy constructors one ends up with much copying or sharing internal data (like arrays or lists). The code style is not that nice.

For completeness:

- There is also *cloning* [`Object.clone()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29) as alternative to a *copy* constructor, but it is slowly falling out of favor, because of its overhead.
- Then there is *serialisation* for copying too, which is still heavily in use, but should not be used here.